# Merge tables from many separate workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I want to merge specific contents of 2713 workbooks into a single worksheet. Lets say the individual files contain sales revenues for different sales outlets.

Each of the workbooks uses only 1 worksheet. Each of those worksheets contains one or more tables in identical format. Worksheets contain no fuctions whatsoever. This sample shows cells A1:E7

A1 contains the number of the specific outlet 
A2 contains the reference date, e.g. 31.12.2014
A3:E3 contain the column headers: No.; Item; Revenue current period; Revenue previous period
A4:E10 contain the info I want transported to the new single file
A11:E11 contains the total amounts
Row 12 is blank
Another table with info for 31.12.2013 starts from row 13.
...

Most of the worksheets have more than just one table. All of them start like the one above. The tables have identical layout.

Unfortunately, the number of products varies a lot (1-250). For the example, I just assumed its 7 products. I don't need the row for headline or total.

How can I get those rows into a new single worksheet?
The outlet number in cell A1 on every sheet should be added in the cell to the right of the cells containing comment.

I want to avoid having to open the 2713 files one after the other in order to copy and paste the info in 2713 drag and drop moves into a merged worksheet.

I hope you can help or its gonna be a long weekend.
Best wishes,
Peter

Comment: What *exactly* is stopping you from doing this?  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: could you show us what have you coded so far?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was thrown this task by my boss who wants data combined in just one file where he can conveniently search for things using Excel's filtering function. I am an economist and use Excel functions regularly. However, I am new to coding and did not make a great start with this problem. Best wishes, Peter

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that when you say tables you mean defined tables of data.
The code below assumes that all tables are the same size (target and source tables).
There's no error checking and minimal testing - so check on some test workbooks first.

```
Sub GetTables()

    Dim colWrkBks As Collection 'Contains path to all workbooks.
    Dim vPath As Variant 'Current workbook path.
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook 'Current workbook.
    Dim wrksht As Worksheet 'Worksheet within wrkBk.
    Dim oListObject As Object 'Tables within wrksht.
    Dim oTargetTable As Object 'The table to hold all the data.
    Dim sTmp As String
    Dim sDirectory As String

    'Make sure you have a table defined to place all the data in.
    'Update worksheet and table name as required.
    Set oTargetTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

    'Get full path of all workbooks in source folder.
    '*Update directory and file extension as required
    Set colWrkBks = New Collection
    sDirectory = "C:\Users\Darren\Documents\Work\New folder\"
    sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & "*.xls*")
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        colWrkBks.Add sDirectory & sTemp
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop

    'Open each workbook and copy the data from source table to target table.
    For Each vPath In colWrkBks
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(vPath, False)

        '1 references the first worksheet - you can use "Sheet1" for a specific sheet name.
        Set wrksht = wrkBk.Worksheets(1)

        'Cycle through each table in the worksheet.
        For Each oListObject In wrksht.ListObjects
            oTargetTable.ListRows.Add
            oListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows("1:" & oListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).Copy _
                oTargetTable.DataBodyRange.Rows(oTargetTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)
        Next oListObject
        wrkBk.Close False
    Next vPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Darren. Thanks a lot for your help! The tables are not defined as such. Its all exported from a database. The columns are the same in all files. The A column holds the serial nos. In every file they start with 1 (cell A4). I need all rows with serial numbers from the first table (there are more underneath). Tables end with sum rows which I don't need and which don't have serial no. File names are all in the same format: 000001.xls - 603450.xls with gaps in numbering. In the new file, there should be a way to identify the source of each row. I hope you can help. Thank you! Peter

Comment: So in each workbook you'll have a range of data going from, for example, row 4 to row 4000.  Each row will have a serial number in column A, and then on row 4001 there'll be totals, and nothing in column A.  
There's then a gap of at least 1 blank row and then another table formatted exactly the same as the previous table.  
You want each of these tables copying without the total rows into a single worksheet.  
How many columns are in each table?  They start on column A and go to which column?  Do they always start in column A?

Comment: On the new single worksheet you also want the source file name on each row, the source sheet name and the source row number?

Comment: Hi Darren. Thanks for your message. The source filename is enough. Best wishes,

Comment: Hi Darren. Right, the actual items I need copied run from rows 4 to e.g. 4003 (with 4000 items). Each row has a serial no. 1-4000. In the example,  row 4004 has the total. Cell A4004 is empty. Row 4005 is empty. Row 4006 has 31.12.2013 in the A column. Row 4007 has the column headers of the 2013 table - identical to the 2014 table sitting on top. Rows 4008 through 8007 may hold 4000 items for 2013. The tables both within and across files have the same columns containing the same type of info. The number of items varies.

Comment: Yes, I don't need the rows that hold the "total". Its always 5 columns (A through E). Of course it would be ideal to have the content of all tables from all files, merged into one worksheet. But then every row in the new worksheet would need the year as well as the source to allow for a clear identification. Years are given as 31.12.201X. In the example, that is in cells A2 (31.12.2014), A4006 (31.12.2013) etc. In terms of identifying the source, cell A1 is just as good for me as the file name. Either is fine. Whichever is easier.